# JxBrowser - Limit maximum number of connections per server / proxy

Tags: jxbrowser

I am evaluating JxBrowser 6.14 at present and have a requirement to limit number of parallel connections per server. How can be this controlled? Is there any chromium switch available that can be used?

For example: Firefox supports configuration of "network.http.*" preferences via about:config to control such settings.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser library doesn't have a public API that allows configuring the number of connections per server due to the fact that this number is not configurable in Google Chrome.

Also please note, that Chromium developers team limited this number to 6 and has not considered yet to [increase this number](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=285567). In addition they do not accept requests to [make it configurable](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85323) in some way.